# Is it possible to force clear cache users browser on new build version?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In create-react-app can i force clear cache user if i have a new build version of my web app? I have this problem with my staging site that i have to clear cache my browser so that it can reflect my changes.

Comment: what about showing a pop, telling the user to refresh or clear cache?

Comment: Remember that ISP also cache stuff. I had the same issue on a simple webpack config where I always exported main.bundle.js. The ISP remembers (or somewhere) and returns the old one. The right way would be to do something like `main.${someRandomGen}.bundle.js`

Comment: @usama https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk i did this.

Answer (score -1):

To show the latest version of your app you have to unregister service worker. So what service worker does is give functionality similar to redux-persist. It saves css and html locally to provide better performance in consecutive refresh. So whenever you deploy new changes it will not reflect. By default create-react-app have integration of service workers. Below is the code the unregister:-

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This isn't a solution at all. Some apps require the service worker for PWA capabilities and push notifications.